# Get a Folder in the PyroCMS Files Module

Tags: php, pyrocms

How do I find a Folder, and get the ID of this folder i PyroCMS Files module, using PHP.
Ideally I would like to do this below, but I cant find the function for get folder by name.

```
    // This does not work
    $folder = Files::find_folder_by_name("MyFolder");
    $folder_id = $folder ["data"]["id"]; 

    // This part works fine
    if($folder_id==NULL) 
    {
        $ar =   Files::create_folder(0, "MyFolder");
        $folder_id = $ar["data"]["id"]; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not function named `find_folder_by_name`. Try following with model:

```
$folder = $this->file_folders_m->get_by('name', 'MyFolder');

if(!$folder) 
{
    $ar =   Files::create_folder(0, "MyFolder");
    $folder_id = $ar["data"]["id"]; 
}

echo $folder->id; // Get folder ID
```

`$folder` variable returns object.